# How to add legend for Pie chart in Android plot?

Tags: android, androidplot

[image]

I am using Android Plot(http://androidplot.com/) library to draw a Pie chart and Pie chart draw is fine but I want legend and its customisation as shown in attached image so please guide me to do same in Android Plot library.

Comment: MPA Chart library best for pie chart

Comment: @DarshanKachhadiya: I want to generate same graphs as like in IOS graph library "core plot" and all other are working fine in android plot.

Answer (score 1):

Pie chart legends were added in Androidplot 1.5.0 but is disabled by default.  To enable:

```
pieChart.legend.setVisible(true);
```

[Configuration of the legend](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/docs/legend.md) works the same way it does for other series types in Androidplot.  For example, you can configure a single column with 4 rows:

```
pie.getLegend().setTableModel(new DynamicTableModel(1, 4));
```

Or a single row with 4 columns (shown below):

```
pie.getLegend().setTableModel(new DynamicTableModel(4, 1));
```

[image]